# TYPO3 how to modify TCA?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

TYPO3 9, but is probably independent of TYPO3 version

I have installed `news` and `eventnews`. `eventnews` adds a field `location_simple` to the table `tx_news_domain_model_news`. In the backend this is of type `input`. I want it to be of type `text`. Therefore I added a file `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_news.php` to my sitepackage:

```
<?php
if( !defined('TYPO3_MODE') ) {
    die ('Access denied.');
}

// Modify location simple
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_news']['columns']['location_simple']['config']['type'] = 'text';
```

But this has no effect.

My sitepackage is included at last position, so it should be able to overwrite the TCA of `eventnews`. What is correct the magic for this?

Comment: Have you cleared the system cache? is your change visible in the configuration module? you may need an extension dependency to make clear the order. / do you need a change in the SQL-field declaration?

Comment: The system cache is cleared, but the change is not visible in the configuration module. What do you mean with "change in the SQL field declaration"?

Comment: And an extension dependency does not solve the problem. I was wondering whether there is a need to load the TCA with special functions and merge it with other special functions I once saw somewhere but I can' t recall where.

Comment: extension depenendcies force a special order of extension and so the order of includes or enhancements to the gathered and cached configuration files. if using `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/...` doesn't work have a look into `ext_tables.php` and `ext_localconfiguration.php` of all involved extensions. these files might modify the TCA, after it has been build by concatenating the TCA configurations. in this case you need to build the same (dirty) TCA modification.

Comment: `eventnews` adds the field via `addTCAcolums` which is just an `array_merge`. It seems to be a good way. Could it be that `Overrides` is working alphabetically? The extension key of my site package begins with a 'c' thus being always before 'eventnews'.

Comment: I made a test extension called `test` just containing the relevant overrides file - and it works! So the overrides order really seems to be alphabetically by extension name! Huhh. I would say this is a workaround but the overrides mechanism should be reformed somehow.

Comment: I think the override order is (also) dependent on extension dependencies (otherwise you never could change in an extension named 'aaaa' something of extension 'zzzz'). your extension should depend on `ext:eventnews`.

Comment: Yes, it does, and it is definitely called before `eventnews`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me: rename my site package extension so that it has an extension key alphabetically after 'e'.

It seems as if the files in /Configuration/TCA/Overrides are read alphabetically. In my case I wanted to override `eventnews`. So my site package extension key had to begin with a letter in [f-z].

Answer (score 0):

You must add the extension 'news' to the dependencies of your extension. Then this will have the effect that the TCA of extension 'news' is included before your extension's TCA code is executed.

file **ext_emconf.php**:

```
$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = [
...
    'constraints' =>
        [
            'depends' =>
                [
                    'typo3' => '11.5.0-12.4.99',
                    'php' => '7.4.0-8.2.99',
                    'news' => '9.3.0-11.2.99',
                ],
        ],
);
```

file **composer.json**:

```
"require": {
    "typo3/cms-core": "^11.5 || ^12.4",
    "php": "^7.4 || ^8",
    "news": "^9.3 || ^10 || ^11"
},
```

From the docs:

"If your extension modifies another extension, you actively need to make sure your extension is loaded after the extension you are modifying. This can be achieved by registering that other extension as a dependency (or suggestion) of yours."

see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/HowTo/ExtendingTca/StoringChanges/Index.html#storing-changes-extension .